# How to individually turn off/on USB ports? Is it possible to connect a usb hub to PC and then control the USB ports of the HUB programatically?

Tags: powershell, cmd, usb

I have a windows 8.1 machine. 
I need two USB ports. How can I disable either of them ? 
Is there any command? Or any script/ code ?

Comment: Might help if you described in more detail what you are trying to accomplish. As such there is no way to disable a specific USB port, since they are handled by the hub. You can disable the hub but then all ports connected to it will be disabled.

Comment: Ok. That did help. So even if we buy an external hub and try to manage individual ports ( programaticaly ), it wont help. right ?

Comment: Not individual ports, but if you get an external USB hub it will show as a hub device and you can enable/disable that. That way you would require a hub for each device, which may or may not be doable. Also finding the specific hub to disable may be tricky, I have not tried that ever.

Comment: Are you trying to disable a particular hardware connected to these USB ports or just USB ports?

Comment: I am connecting two mobile phones ( windows 8 phones) to two different USB ports.
Now, when I run projectmyscreenApp ( windows phone app installed on the PC) it sends message to only one mobile device. So I want to direct the app to particular mobile device by disabling the other.

Comment: Thanks Sami and kekimian for helping me. 
My machine is having USB 2.0 ports and USB 3.0 ports. Is it possible to disable either of these individually ? 
Wont USB 2.0 ports all be in the same hub ? So wont I be able to disable that particular hub ?

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to disable the usb devices ( not power them down)...try usbdeview from Nirsoft. I have used that in the past with some success. 
http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html